# Tracking Wordpress plugin cpu/memory load - is it possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, nginx

I'm going to use VPS with nginx and PHP 7 installed, CMS Wordpress.

There are many different plugins and some of them aren't very well written. I know that chasing the best of the best is usually not a good idea, but I recently discovered that `Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer` plugin created an extremely high cpu-load, increasing admin panel loading time up to 6 times.

I need a way to track which plugin is heavy and which isn't. In the past, there was a `P3 Plugin Profiler` (plugin for Wordpress). But it's outdated and doesn't support PHP 7. There are currently no plugins that can replace it.

Is there some nginx or php extensions that will help me to accomplish my goal? I also heard about New Relic, but this one is really expensive.

Comment: I feel like this may be a better suited question asked on the wordpress forums. Just a bonus stat; 63% of people who took the 2018 survey stated they dread working on wordpress stuff https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms

Comment: That's weird. Drupal is much better compared to Joomla.